# How can I construct a string literal during program execution using a string literal and a character array without including the string library?

Tags: c, parameters, arduino, type-conversion

I am trying to concatenate `"Label:  "` and `*msg` and use the result as a parameter in a function. `*msg` is a pointer to a character array. Other examples of this function use either string literals or macros of string literals as parameters. I unfortunately cannot use the string type because I cannot include the string library because of program size constraints. My program will run on an Arduino Mega type board.

```
// creation of msg
char msg[10];
sprintf_P(msg, PSTR("  %i"), (int)(thermalManager.current_temperature[0]));

// concatenate string literal with msg
// something = "Label:  " + *msg

// use in function
MENU_ITEM(function,something,dummy_function);
```

The program is a Marlin variant for 3D printers.

Edit: Also, the second parameter in MENU_ITEM() cannot be msg as far as I can tell, the only form that I've been able to get it to take without a compilation error is a string literal.

Comment: `man snprintf` or `memcpy` basically this is also C not C++

Comment: Literals only exist in source code.

Comment: @molbdnilo What are my options then, since the second parameter in MENU_ITEM needs to be a string literal?

Comment: if you actually need string literals you will have to type in all possible options...
or you need to make your preprocessor macro do something with concatenation which iirc is `##`

Comment: Depending on what the macro does, there may be an option that involves not using the macro. It could also be impossible. There is no way to tell without seeing what it expands to.

Comment: msg is updated many times a second, and can be any number between 0 and like 300, so preprocessor concatenation is not a good choice. The macro MENU_ITEM allows msg to be displayed on an LCD screen. I may need to abandon use of the macro in this case and investigate a different way of displaying the info on the screen.

Comment: I'm unfortunately away from the code at the moment so I cannot post what the macro expands to, though I will do so tomorrow. Thank you all for your suggestions so far.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think it's [this macro](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd/menu/menu.h#L442).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the concatenation in the `sprintf` above...

```
// creation of msg
char msg[8+10];
sprintf_P(msg, PSTR("Label:  %i"), (int)(thermalManager.current_temperature[0]));

// use in function
MENU_ITEM(function,msg,dummy_function);
```

if this doesn't work (as it seems) because the type of memory used by the menu item must be "program data" then there is a serious possibility that what is being asked is just impossible.

In many micros program data is read-only and must be "flashed" with a special procedure during bootstrap. If this is the case and for some unspecified reason the menu item must come from that area then it is by definition impossible to create a menu item with a content computed at run time with that library.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second parameter of macro MENU_ITEM() will not take msg, though it does take something like `"this is a string literal"`.

Comment: @Dillon what is the error (given by the compiler?) if you do as this answer suggests?

Comment: error: initializer fails to determine size of '__c'  . The full error readout can be found here: https://gist.github.com/dillthedude/0d7cb595b30046ec2e96b380ab5190dd

Comment: @Dillon Took me a moment to find it all (please give the name of the library used next time, thanks), but the definition is `#define PSTR(s) (__extension__({static const char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))`   The macro `PROGMEM` is defined as `#define PROGMEM __attribute__((section(".progmem.data"))) which puts the string into a special section in the executable in case the compiler is GCC or blank otherwise. That is the reason the compiler does not want to eat anything different from string literals. What to do about? Good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf_P()`, just like you did, but with two `%s` format specifiers and a buffer. Even better, use `snprintf_P()` to make sure you are not overflowing the buffer.

```c
const char *s1 = "first";
const char *s2 = "second";
#define BUFF_SIZE 20
char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

sprintf_P(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, PSTR("%s%s"), s1, s2);
```